# Repeater and Bandwidth consumption

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, bandwidth, repeater

Does using a repeater to increase WiFi signal means I will use double the Internet Bandwidth that I use for connecting directly to the Router, in other way if I consume 10 megabyte by connecting directly to the router to www.anything.com, will I consume 20 megabyte if I used a Repeater?

Comment: It is quite difficult to read your question and that's why i do not post an asnwer, i think you are mixings concepts, i.e(i'll compare with wired networks) if i've a host, and this host have a wired cat5 link to another switch and the switch to another switch if i put more links between switchs it doesnt increase my bandwidth just will add redundancy, it is the same if you add repeaters or access points there are some tecnologies to merge links as etherchannel. but they are not easy to set just pluggin cables or enabling access points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The repeater ends up using twice the Wi-Fi airtime in your house when forwarding traffic from the main router to the far clients, but it doesn't significantly affect how much Internet bandwidth is used on your broadband link.

Comment: I would say technically, it doesn't have *any* effect on how much internet bandwidth is used. Sure you could argue it may result in more TCP retransmits but then it could also result in less.